# How to handle entity manager closing on unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine my tests, and sometimes I want to test an UNIQUE exception, relying that doctrine will give me the proper one. But after getting this kind of exceptions from doctrine the entity manager is closed and I cant continue to test with it. For now I'm getting a new one and updating the classes that uses it, but this is far from ideal - the setup is too large and the performance is penalized.
I know an alternative would be to use mocks but it would be far too complicated IMO.  Maybe controlling the flush, but it seems too much work as well.

Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: What kind of tests you want to use?
Unit, Integration, Functional?

Your test depends on current DB state, but it shouldn't.

I think you only need to unit test your business logic, and test Unique separately. If your dependecies were tested, there's no point to test them again.

Comment: The problem is with unit tests. I understand I shouldn't test the ORM, but having only a single category with x name in a client is a business requirement and the easier way to implement it is through SQL Unique Constraints.